# Change predicted probabilities to prediction in PyTorch NN

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, multilabel-classification

My outputs are like this

> tensor([[-0.2713, -0.6608, -0.4430, -0.0207, -0.4408, -0.3075],
> [-0.2713, -0.6608, -0.4430, -0.0207, -0.4408, -0.3075],
> [-0.2713, -0.6608, -0.4430, -0.0207, -0.4408, -0.3075],
> [-0.2713, -0.6608, -0.4430, -0.0207, -0.4408, -0.3075]],
> grad_fn=)
>
> labels: tensor([5, 6, 6, 6], dtype=torch.int32)`

instead of both being length 4 tensors

how do I change the outputs to a length 4 tensor
please help thank you

I don't know how to find the classes of the probabilities

Comment: Use `torch.max.(<tensor>, dim = 1)` which will return a tuple (max value, maximum index) for each example in the batch

Comment: Why is your output shape of `(4, 6)`, while your label shape is `(5,6,6,6)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.